# Is there a way to interact with Word's spell & grammar check programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, spell-checking

I'm looking for an efficient way to interact programmatically (outside of Word) with Word's **spell** and **grammar** check functionalities.

I found this 11-year-old article but I am sure there is a better way to achieve this today?

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-check-spelling-and-grammar-in-microsoft-office-word/

Yet I was unable to find anything recent on the topic - could someone point me toward a good way to get started with 2019 products?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a COM reference to `Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library`, then you can do something like:

```
var app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();    
var spellingIsCorrect = app.CheckSpelling("hello");
var grammarIsCorrect = app.CheckGrammar("is my grammar correct?");
```

Comment: Thanks, finally found something on Google based on your example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-programmatically-check-spelling-in-documents?view=vs-2019